# Cannot initialize recycler view in activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

please help me, I  am trying to initialize the simplest recycler view from the stack and it's still resisting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    tools:context=".CostInvoiceAttachments">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/CLI_rows_RV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/CL_Layout_TV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CL_Size_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Size"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/NumberDescription"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CL_Title_TV" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CL_Date_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Date"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CL_Title_TV" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CL_Title_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TitleDescription"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/NumberDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/Size_hint"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TitleDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TitleDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/Name_hint"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DateDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/Date_hint"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/CL_Date_TV"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CL_Title_TV" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter

```
package com.platform.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.platform.R;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuRecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity context;

    public MenuRecAdapter(ArrayList<String> mList){
        this.mList = mList;
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return mList.size();
    }

    public RecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cost_invoice_attachments_item, viewGroup, false);
        RecViewHolder pvh = new RecViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder holder, int i){
        holder.menuTeXT.setText(mList.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

View holder

```
package com.platform.adapters;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.platform.R;

public class RecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView menuTeXT;

    public RecViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        menuTeXT = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.CL_Date_TV);
    }
}
```

initialization:

```
 fun initRecyclerView() {
        val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        list.add("something1")
        list.add("something2")

        val recyclerView = binding.CLIRowsRV
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        linearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        val menuRecAdapter = MenuRecAdapter(list)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(menuRecAdapter)
        //print(recyclerView.adapter.toString())

    }
```

i give up up i tried evrything this isn't even what i starded with and it still no show no error
i tried adding working recycler from fragment (from the same app) no good won't work
please pretty please help
Edit 1: whole activity

```
package com.platform

import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.platform.adapters.CostInvoicesAttachmentsAdapter
import com.platform.adapters.CostInvoicesRecyclerAdapter
import com.platform.adapters.MenuRecAdapter
import com.platform.api.EmsApi
import com.platform.databinding.ActivityCostInvoiceAttachmentsBinding
import com.platform.pojo.costInvoice.attachments.Attachments
import com.platform.pojo.costInvoices.CostInvoices
import com.platform.utils.ErrorUtil
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import javax.inject.Inject


@AndroidEntryPoint
class CostInvoiceAttachments : AppCompatActivity() , CostInvoicesAttachmentsAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    @Inject
    lateinit var emsApi: EmsApi

    @Inject
    lateinit var ee : ErrorUtil

    var attachments: Attachments=Attachments()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCostInvoiceAttachmentsBinding
    var index: Int =-1
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCostInvoiceAttachmentsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cost_invoice_attachments)
        index = intent.getIntExtra("index",-1)
        initRecyclerView()
        //getAttachmentAttachments()
       




    }
    /**
     * Pobranie załączniki faktury kosztowej
     * @author Rafał Pasternak
     **/
    private fun getAttachmentAttachments() {
        val call = emsApi.getCostInvoiceAttachments(
            index
        )
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) =
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    var rawJsonString:String? = response.body()?.string()
                    rawJsonString="{\"Attachments\":"+rawJsonString+"}"
                    attachments= Gson().fromJson(rawJsonString, Attachments::class.java)
                    initRecyclerView()
                } else {
                    val errorUtil = ee.parseError(response)
                    if (errorUtil != null) {
                        openDialog(errorUtil.message)
                    } else
                        openDialog("${resources.getString(R.string.FailedToConnect)} ${response.message()}")
                }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("APP", t.localizedMessage)
                Log.e("APP", t.message.toString())
            }
        })
    }
    /**
     * Metoda do wyświetlenia komunikatu użytkownikowi
     * @author Rafał Pasternak
     **/
    fun openDialog(message: String) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.messageTitle)) //jako res string
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
            }
            .show()
    }
    fun initRecyclerView() {
        val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        list.add("something1")
        list.add("something2")

        val recyclerView = binding.CLIRowsRV
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        linearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        val menuRecAdapter = MenuRecAdapter(list)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(menuRecAdapter)
        //print(recyclerView.adapter.toString())

    }
    /**
     * Metoda nadpisująca metodę z interfejsu onItemClickListener
     * odsyła do wybranej przez użytkownika umowy
     * @author Rafał Pasternak
     * **/
    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item $position clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var index=attachments.attachments[position].id

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do differently than a tutorial or another similar existing SO question?

Comment: i literatly copied all code from working fragment to activity and layout adapter etc and no recycler, same for current code copied from tutorial on stack overflow where guy had issue with no adapter despite adding it

Comment: Can you show us the whole code of the activity not only the init method?

Comment: comming right up

Comment: Well i pushed what i had to fragment and it's working i don't know why but work around is better than not working at all

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be the way how you inflate the binding. You are using 2 setContentView in your Activity which seems to be the last that makes the binding not inflate. Can you try this please:

Remove this code in your activity:

```
binding = ActivityCostInvoiceAttachmentsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)       
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cost_invoice_attachments)
```

and put this instead:

```
val binding: ActivityCostInvoiceAttachmentsBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_cost_invoice_attachments)
```

This should work. I haven’t tried it but it should work.

Here is a link about How to inflate binding layout into Activity:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data